# How to distinguish between different wsdl locations in one pom.xml - Maven

Tags: java, web-services, maven, wsdl, maven-3

Is there a possibility to distinguish between multiple configurations of wsdl webservices in maven?

I have `one application` which can run on `test, stage and prod environments`. And I have to use one webservice. The webservice has `3 different wsdl locations`. For `test, stage and prod.`

**Is there a way in maven to say if I want to build my application for prod just use the webservice location for prod. And the same also for stage and test?**

I have a wsdl import configuration which works fine for a single non-dynamical part.

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.3</version>
 <executions>
     <execution>
         <goals>
             <goal>wsimport</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
             <wsdlFiles>
                 <wsdlFile>wsdlFile_live.wsdl</wsdlFile>
             </wsdlFiles>
             <vmArgs>
                 <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all</vmArg>
                 <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
             </vmArgs>
             <packageName>com.example.schema</packageName>
             <wsdlLocation>http://liveLocation/?wsdl</wsdlLocation>

         </configuration>
         <id>wsimport-generate-_live.wsdl</id>
         <phase>generate-sources</phase>
     </execution>
 </executions>
 <dependencies>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
         <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.1</version>
     </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <configuration>
     <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxws-wsimport</sourceDestDir>
     <xnocompile>true</xnocompile>
     <verbose>true</verbose>
     <extension>true</extension>
     <catalog>${basedir}/src/jax-ws-catalog.xml</catalog>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: To me it sounds like a bad idea to having to build the same base multiple times to get test,stage,prod. Why not just select the correct WSDL from an environment variable telling the java whether to get the dev-wsdl, the test-wsdl... or prod-wsdl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating profiles in maven is one possibility to build different applications with different scopes.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <build>
         ....
       </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <build>
            ....
       </build>
    </profile>  
</profiles>
```

In the profile property you can set **dependencies**, **resourves**, **plugins**, **configurations** and so on.

To build a specific profile you have to type `mvn -P` followed by the **profile ID**

In my case it looks like this: `mvn -Ptest clean install` or `mvn -Pprod clean install`

Answer (score 1):

You can  use environment variables to store your wsdl file and pass to maven system properties. For example, say on Linux you want to access environment variable MY_VARIABLE. You can use a system property in your pom file.

```
<properties>
...
<!-- Default value for my.variable can be defined here -->
<my.variable>foo</my.variable>
...
```

...

`${my.variable}`

Set the property value on the maven command line:

mvn clean package -Dmy.variable=$MY_VARIABLE