# Soap Client with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jenkins, soap-client

I have a separate WSDL URL for each environment, like

DEV   URL-1 ,
SIT   URL-2,
PROD  URL-3

I want to create a soap client in such a way that if we are deploying the application using this soap client on DEV then soap should point URL-1, if we deploy in SIT it should point URL-2 for PROD it should point URL-3. I am using MAVEN for generating soap client.

I don't want to change soap URL in pom.xml each time when I am deploying the application in a different environment.

We are using Jenkins to build the application and deploy in different environment

Can you help me on this?

Comment: What maven plugin are you using to generate client files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the maven plugin you are using to generate client files, but my advice is anyway to create different maven profiles for all your environments.

Please check the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796027/how-to-distinguish-between-different-wsdl-locations-in-one-pom-xml-maven) and the answer from Patrick.